# How To: Display taxonomy translations based on a user's view

Tags: php, drupal, internationalization, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've been trying to figure out how exactly to **display a set of taxonomy terms according the current user's language**.

I have:

- all the appropriate modules installed (Internationalization, Content Translation, Taxonomy Translation, Internationalization Views, etc.)
- set up translations for each taxonomy term (English/Spanish)
- added a filter for 'Taxonomy term: Language' via the "Internationalization Views" module.

Unfortunately, it won't dump out the *Spanish* terms. The English ones are working fine.

Any links to articles on how to get this to work or assistance would be a great help.

**THANKS IN ADVANCE!!**

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have all of those installed and setup as well (and complete) as you do I decided to hunt around on forums.  I found an article which seems like a similar problem to what you are having.  The default language terms were always showing up in this post [Localize terms show always the default language](http://drupal.org/node/1070256).

Hopefully this post/article has some helpful information/steps on how to resolve this issue, check out post [13](http://drupal.org/node/1070256#comment-4454344) in that thread.

Comment: Appreciate your assistance! I just posted the solution I found. Your solution works on a term-by-term basis so it's also an acceptable way to handle it. I just prefer to manage everything through the GUI rather than hard-coding everything in there.

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done with Internationalization Views (http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews)

I had just misconfigured my view. It was an easy oversight to fix.

I did the following:

1. Created a taxonomy vocabulary and set the "Multilingual Options" to "Translate."
2. Edited each of the terms and clicked the "Translate" tab at the top of the page. Must make sure the initial term has 'English' selected as the language.
3. Added a translation for Spanish and saved it
4. Created a Taxonomy Term view that dumped out each of the Term names
5. Set one of the filter criteria to Taxonomy term: Lanuage (= Current user's language)

Viola. Easy enough.